# Tensorflow categorical data with vocabulary list - Expected binary or Unicode string, got [0,1,2,…]

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, machine-learning, categorical-data

I'm brand new to machine learning (having just completed the Google machine learning crash course) and thought it would be good to try my hand at a Kaggle competition as a good starter to some real problem solving. I'm using Tensorflow and Python 3, all up to date (the Kaggle online Jupyter notebook)

The data is formatted in a dataframe like below

```
|Identity | Cuisine | Ingredients                |
|---------|---------|----------------------------|
|1        | italian | [beans, milk,..., tomatoes]|
|2        | indian  | [chicken, curry leaf,...]  |
```

I have made a vocabulary list generator to create a vocabulary set, and replace instances of those words in the ingredients array with the index of the ingredient in the vocabulary set, so my original data looks like below.

```
|Identity | Cuisine | Ingredients |
|---------|---------|-------------|
|1        | italian |[0, 1,..., 4]|
|2        | indian  |[5, 6,...]   |
```

I separate the labels (cuisine) and the features (ingredients) into 2 separate dataframes for ease, and I am using a `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` and subsequent `tf.feature_column.indicator_column` for the ingredients array.

I now however have an issue with my model not being able to read the `ingredients` column, and get the error

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

My input function is as follows

```
def input_fn(features,labels,batch_size,num_epochs=None,shuffle=True):
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,labels))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(10000)

    feature_batch, label_batch = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return feature_batch, label_batch
```

which is fed into a simple function as below

```
training_func = lambda: input_fn(training_example,training_target,batch_size)
validati_func = lambda: input_fn(validation_example,validation_target,batch_size)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(optimizer, 5.0)

classifier.train(
    input_fn=training_func,
    steps=steps_per_period
)
```

My question is how do I fix this TypeError

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

(for clarity)

In addition I also want to know if there a best practice for handling this format of data? (and if there is any built-in functionality to handle this)

Since this might be a code heavy question, I added my entire code to an online [Pastebin paste](https://pastebin.com/ge5542gx) so you can check out the code. The dataset I am using is from the Kaggle [What's Cooking competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/whats-cooking-kernels-only)

Comment: The article https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-gender-from-name-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-448d64553044 predicts the gender from names which is comparable to the kaggle dataset.